# MySQL boolean - flipping the value?

Tags: mysql, boolean

MySQL uses TinyINT to serve as a boolean field. Given the possible options of 0 and 1, I decided that I'd flip values like this:

```
UPDATE table
SET boolean_field = ABS(boolean_field - 1)
WHERE Circle-K = 'Strange things are afoot'
```

So you either go 1 -> 0 -> ABS(0) = 0

or 0 -> -1 -> ABS(-1) = 1

now I'm curious if this is *acceptable* or *horrifying* to the real programmers?

/me is a beginner

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Why not simply use:

```
UPDATE the_table
   SET boolean_field = NOT boolean_field
WHERE ...
```

Makes your intention a lot easier to read

Comment: +1 for added readability while (probably) not sacrificing speed.

Answer (score 18):

You can also use `field` = 1 - `field` or `field` = ! `field`

Comment: @Pratik: I'm sure it is an answer (as long as it does what OP wants), thank you for your mention.

Comment: @zerkms good answer especially when you use small unsigned int as boolean

Comment: @seddik why "especially"?

Comment: @zerkms I don't know if it works with booleans or not, but with int it sure works.