# Select boolean but reverse the value

Tags: mysql

I am working on a table with a boolean field, but the field name is negative so that the boolean is a double negative.

```
not_registered TINYINT(1)
```

I want to select it with an alias as "registered" instead, so it makes more sense. I didn't create this column, I just have to work with it.

Comment: I'd avoid using negative field names. Don't you think it'd be easier to read if you used `registered`/`NOT registered` instead of `NOT not_registered`/`not_registered`?

Comment: @Jonathan Yes, definitely. I didn't create the schema.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `NOT` negation operator.  For example:

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    NOT not_registered AS registered
FROM users;
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use just `NOT not_registered` in your select.

Check also [MySQL boolean - flipping the value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490759/mysql-boolean-flipping-the-value).